# show html image side by side inside for loop

Tags: html, image

MY images are being generated by iterating through a `for` loop. I want to show the images side by side instead of one below the other. How?

> .html

```
    <div class="tab-pane" id="5b">

        <div class="media">
            <p>Company Logo</p>
            <img class="rounded-circle account-img" width="200" height="200" src="/media/{{ logo.image_file }}"/>
        </div>

        <h4>Design works</h4>

        <a href="/agency/image_upload/design">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="background-color:royalblue;color:white;width:150px;
                height:40px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                Add Design works
            </button>
        </a>
        <br>

        {% for design in designs %}

        <div class="media">
            <img class="img" src="/media/{{ design.image_file }}" alt="Snow">
        </div>

        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

> .css

```
.img {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;

        /*Scale down will take the necessary specified space that is 100px x 100px without stretching the image*/
        object-fit: scale-down;

    }
```

Comment: try putting the div outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a container for the images then put all your .media tags there.:

```
<div class="media-container">
    {% for design in designs %}

       <div class="media">
          <img class="img" src="/media/{{ design.image_file }}" alt="Snow">
       </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>



.media-container {
   display: flex;
}
```

the default direction is row so no worries about that.

Flexbox is incredible powerful. Here a perfect guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: it's not working, i now posted the full code, please see

Comment: @afsara_ben please notice the tag wrapper .media-container over your loop in my answer.